# Darf man „überzeugen + zu + Infinitiv“ verwenden?

Tags: grammar, verb, preposition

Also wenn ich „I persuaded him to come with us“ sagen will, darf ich einfach

> Ich habe ihn überzeugt, mitzukommen.

sagen oder muss ich unbedingt die Präposition *von* verwenden?

> Ich habe ihn davon überzeugt, mitzukommen.

oder

> Ich habe ihn davon überzeugt, dass er mitkommt (mitkomme?).

<strike>Die Frage gilt nicht nur für dieses konkrete Verb, als auch für andere Verben, die eine bestimmte Präposition erfordern.</strike>

Comment: *Die Frage gilt nicht nur für dieses konkrete Verb, als auch für andere Verben, die eine bestimmte Präposition erfordern*: Dann ist sie *too broad*, weil keine Antwort alle Verben behandeln kann.

Comment: Zur Meta-Frage (die nicht hierher gehört): Weil niemand eine Frage damit markiert hat, z.B. auch nicht du.

Comment: @chirlu: Wenn keine allgemeine Antwort für alle Verben gegeben werden kann, dann loesche ich diesen Satz.

Comment: @chirlu: Ja, ich weiss die Mechanik, wie es so ein Tag nicht gibt, aber ich dachte, dass weil die Rektionen so wichtig bei der Deutschen Sprache sind, vielleicht suche ich nach einem falschen Begriff. Habe aber das Tag zugefuegt

Comment: @chirlu Bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Frage wirklich too broad wäre. Es kann ja durchaus sein, dass es ein (unbewusstest) Pattern gibt, nachdem Muttersprachler entscheiden, ob "von" hinzugefügt wird oder nicht. Oder vllt gibt es sogar wirklich nur eine Gruppe bestimmter Verben, wo dies möglich / nicht möglich ist. — Zugegeben, da ich nicht glaube, dass man dazu auf die Schnelle etwas im Internet findet, ist das mit Sicherheit ein Thema für eine sehr ausführliche Recherche. Und dann ist es einfacher, sich auf ein Verb zu konzentrieren.

Comment: @Em1: Um dein Verb _konzentrieren_ aufzugreifen, es verhält sich anders als _überzeugen_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Korrekt wären in diesem Fall beide Versionen. Du kannst sowohl

> Ich habe ihn überzeugt, mitzukommen.

als auch

> Ich habe ihn davon überzeugt, mitzukommen.

verwenden. Die erste Version ist hier etwas umgangssprachlicher und die meisten Deutschen würden diese Version in alltäglichen Gesprächen verwenden. Die zweite („ausgeschriebene“) Version wäre eher im Schriftverkehr zu finden.

Deine dritte Variante

> Ich habe ihn davon überzeugt, dass er **mitkommt**. ("mitkommt" ist hier richtig)

ist zwar aus grammatikalischer Sicht korrekt, aber für mich als Muttersprachler klingt es doch etwas merkwürdig und den Satz würde man so sehr wahrscheinlich nirgendwo wiederfinden.

Um also auf Deine Frage zu antworten: Nein, es gibt keine Regel, nach welcher Du „von“ in Deinem Satz verwenden musst.

Comment: *Ich habe ihn davon überzeugt, dass er mitkommt.* klingt in meinen Ohren nicht so schlimm. Es ist vielleicht eher umgangssprachlich, kommt aber durchaus vor. Es klingt hier aber ungewöhnlich, da *Ich habe ihn (davon) überzeugt, dass er mitkommt* eher so wirkt, als ob *er* das Mitkommen einfach nicht glaubt (man muss ihn von der Tatsache überzeugen statt ihn zur Tat zu bewegen). Im Alltag ist diese Uneindeutigkeit meist irrelevant.

Comment: Ersetze »dass er mitkommt« durch »dass die Erde eine Scheibe ist« und schon sieht man, dass Variante 3 genau so korrekt ist, wie Varianten 1 und 2; nur dass in diesem Fall die Kürzung nicht angewendet werden kann, weil das Bezogene wechselt. Deswegen 0. (Der Rest der Antwort wäre +1-würdig, dadurch aber nicht mehr.)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort und die Kommentaren dazu. Jetzt ist alles klar.